# Network Graph - Is there a way to hide a specific node on click in network graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to hide a node on click in network graph. How can I hide a node in Network graph using highcharts?

I already tried removing the node in the series and updating the chart. Is there a better way?

[image: Network Graph]

Answer (score 2):

To hide a specific point on a `click` event use `remove` method:

```
plotOptions: {
    networkgraph: {
        ...,
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    this.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is a bug in a `networkgraph` chart, related with `remove` method (reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10565), so additionally you need to use a workaround:

```
Highcharts.wrap(
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph.prototype, 'generatePoints',
    function(p) {
        if (this.nodes) {
            this.nodes.forEach(function(node) {
                node.destroy();
            });
            this.nodes.length = 0;
        }
        return p.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
);
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m9tjb481/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#remove